# Преобразование строки в массив чисел

Tags: c#, linq

Есть строка, в которой символы и числа. Эту строку нужно преобразовать в целочисленный массив

```
string str = "2, 1, 1, 2, 4, 6, 7";

string newStr = str.Replace(",", string.Empty);

int[] x = newStr.Split(' ').Select(int.Parse).ToArray();
```

Я это сделал таким образом, но можно ли это сделать в одно строку через Linq? Почему-то Split работает только с одним символом, если работать напрямую и добавить кроме пробела еще запятую,

```
str.Split(' ', ',')
```

то перестает работать

Comment: `str.Split(new char[] { ',', ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)`

Comment: Split(new[] { ", " })

Comment: @Alexander Petrov можете пояснить из-за чего происходит исключение, если не использовать StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries

Comment: из-за того, что разделителями являются два символа строка `", "`  будет разделена на три элемента из пустых строк. Параметр StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries как раз указывает, что такие элементы надо убрать из результата. Если не убирать, то при попытке получить int из пустой строки получаешь исключение

Comment: _можно ли это сделать в одно строку через Linq?_ ты и так можешь сделать в одну строку: `int[] x = str.Replace(",", string.Empty).Split(' ').Select(int.Parse).ToArray();`

Answer (score -2):

`int[] arr = str.Split(',').Select(n => Convert.ToInt32(n)).ToArray();`

Comment: Те, кто ставили минусы, хотя бы объяснили, за что ставите. А так получается, что просто бездумно щелкнули, хотя решение удовлетворяет всем условиям топикстартера.